# H2 console does not show Spring Boot created tables when configuring and using embedded local persistence even though they are there

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have setup H2 as an embedded persistent database ('Embedded (Local) Database' with `jdbc:h2:[file:][<path>]<databaseName>`) with Spring Boot using Spring Data JPA abstraction, like below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/home/data/embeddeddb;CACHE_SIZE=${spring.datasource.cache.size:131072}
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=someusr
spring.datasource.password=somepwd
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
#spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
```

I placed the `schema.sql` under my project `resources` and see that i am able to perform CRUD operations via the `CrudRepository`. I also enabled h2 console via properties as shown above.

But when i connect to the database from the h2 console using the same URL i specified (above), it does not show me the tables i have created or the configured cache size.

This even though i can use `@Query` methods in my `CrudRepository` to see that they are there.

I am not sure what i am missing here, can someone throw light on this?

Thanks

Comment: I created a simple project with the same properties, and it works for me. I suspect you're connecting to another database, do you use the "someusr" and "somepwd" to log in?

Comment: Thanks @ErikLumme for the response. Yes i am using the same "someusr" and "somepwd" to log in. The funny thing is that for the database url it still allows logging in even though i enter random characters after the db name, for example it allows logging in for both `/home/data/embeddeddb` and `/home/data/embeddeddbsomerandom`. Only in the latter i assume its a different database in the former it should be the one which my spring boot application is using rite?

Comment: One thing to again note here is that this is NOT in-memory but persistent...i see on some other threads on SO that folks use `mem:testdb` saying that's the one created by spring boot. In this case its not in-memory but embedded persistent local db that i want & use here..

Comment: I suggest you set the DB path in `application.properties` to e.g. `/home/data/test1`, then you open the console and connect to `/home/data/test2` (do not connect to test1 first). Then try locating the database(s) on the file system, and see if both the one you created and the one created by the app are indeed in the same folder, or if maybe one of them is created inside your project.

Comment: Hi @ErikLumme, i have already placed the DB path in `application.properties` (the above snippet was from it). I tried what you suggested earlier, taking the earlier example i tried, i don't even see the `/home/data/embeddeddbsomerandom` alongside the `/home/data/embeddeddb` even after connecting to it from the h2-console. So as you say its getting created somewhere else...i thought the path i enter in the h2 console is the local path to a file on the server, just like i enter in the `application.properties`, now i am confused where its getting created, lemme search for `embeddeddbsomerandom`

Comment: Just to clarify i DO see the database created & present in the path i configured in the `application.properties`, its only the db connection string paths entered in the h2 console that has this weird behavior where the connection goes through but the db file name mentioned while connecting is not present in the path...interestingly the h2 console connection works ONLY if the file names used all start with the original configured filename but appended with random character, Eg: `/home/data/embeddeddbsomerandom` , `/home/data/embeddeddbsomerandom2`, etc work but NOT `/home/data/somerandom`.